# wso2 demo DSS services returns 202 and esb api times out

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm trying to implement the services from the wso2 tutorial found here:

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2015/05/tutorial-hosting-restful-web-services-using-oauth-with-the-wso2-platform-0/

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The DSS service keeps returning a 202 and the ESB API services just times out.

The API code is

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="OrganizationalInfoAPI" context="/internal">
  <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/employees">
    <inSequence>
      <sequence key="conf:/ProcessPayloadForEmpDSSSequence"></sequence>
      <header name="Action" value="urn:insert_employee_operation"></header>
      <call>
        <endpoint>
          <address uri="http://192.168.1.167:9773/services/EmployeesDataService.SOAP11Endpoint/" format="soap11"></address>
        </endpoint>
      </call>
      <sequence key="conf:/ProcessResponseFromEmpDSSService"></sequence>
      <respond></respond>
    </inSequence>
  </resource>
</api>
```

The two sequences are

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
      <p:insert_Employee_operation xmlns:p="http://employees.us.wso2.com">            
        <xs:FirstName xmlns:xs="http://employees.us.wso2.com">$1</xs:FirstName>            
        <xs:LastName xmlns:xs="http://employees.us.wso2.com">$2</xs:LastName>            
        <xs:Team xmlns:xs="http://employees.us.wso2.com">$3</xs:Team>         
      </p:insert_Employee_operation>
    </format>
    <args>
      <arg expression="$.employee.firstName" evaluator="json"></arg>
      <arg expression="$.employee.lastName" evaluator="json"></arg>
      <arg expression="$.employee.team" evaluator="json"></arg>
    </args>
  </payloadFactory>
```

and

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>{"EmployeeRecord":{"EmployeeID":$1, "Status":"Successfully created"}}</format>
    <args>
      <arg expression="$.GeneratedKeys.Entry.ID" evaluator="json"></arg>
    </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
</sequence>
```

I'm missing something.  Any help?

This was in the wso2esb console:

```
[2015-08-03 19:56:20,777] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough st
ream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError
 at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.jav
a:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelo
pe(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSO
APModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBui
lder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder
(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLB
uilderFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java
:55)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.get
Document(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(R
elayUtils.java:107)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(Re
layUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:68)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
diator.java:239)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromCont
inuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:556)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(A
xis2SynapseEnvironment.java:198)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(S
ynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(Synapse
CallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.j
ava:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
WorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLS
treamReaderImpl.java:598)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStr
eamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWra
pper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStr
eamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSX
PStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuild
er.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.jav
a:214)
        ... 21 more
[2015-08-03 19:56:20,779] ERROR - SequenceMediator Error while building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException
(RelayUtils.java:236)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(R
elayUtils.java:111)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(Re
layUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractLis
tMediator.java:68)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMe
diator.java:239)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromCont
inuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:556)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(A
xis2SynapseEnvironment.java:198)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(S
ynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(Synapse
CallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.j
ava:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
WorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
 ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.jav
a:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelo
pe(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSO
APModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBui
lder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder
(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLB
uilderFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java
:55)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.get
Document(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(R
elayUtils.java:107)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLS
treamReaderImpl.java:598)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStr
eamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWra
pper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStr
eamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSX
PStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuild
er.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.jav
a:214)
        ... 21 more
[2015-08-03 19:56:20,781] ERROR - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse encountered an
 exception, No error handlers found - [Message Dropped]
Error while building message
```

Here's the log4j file as requested

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,497] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "POST /internal/employees HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,497] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,498] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,498] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Content-Length: 70[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,498] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Host: 192.168.1.167:8280[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,499] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,499] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,499] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,500] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "{"employee":{"firstName":"Jackie","lastName":"Chan","team":"Finance"}}" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,552]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,572] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "POST /services/EmployeesDataService/employees HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,573] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,573] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,573] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "SOAPAction: [\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,573] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,574] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Host: 192.168.1.167:9773[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,574] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,574] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,574] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,575] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "57[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,575] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "{"insert_Employee_operation":{"FirstName":"Jackie","LastName":"Chan","Team":"Finance"}}[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,575] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,575] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,658] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,659] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,659] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 02:13:21 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,659] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Connection: close[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,659] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,660] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,660] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "114[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,660] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "{"Fault":{"faultcode":"axis2ns1:Client","faultstring":"The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/EmployeesDataService/employees and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.","detail":""}}[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,666] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,666] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,672] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseJsonPath} -  #stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.GeneratedKeys.Entry.ID>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseJsonPath}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,674] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,674] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,675] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 02:13:21 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,675] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,675] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,675] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,675] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,676] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "43[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,677] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "{"EmployeeRecord":{"EmployeeID":, "Status":"Successfully created"}}[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,677] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:13:21,677] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,503]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Shutdown hook triggered.... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,504]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Gracefully shutting down WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,506]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Starting to switch to maintenance mode... {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,506]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} -  Stopping Pass-through HTTPS Listener.. {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,508]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} -  Stopping Pass-through HTTP Listener.. {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,508]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} -  HTTPS Listener shutdown. {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,509]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} -  HTTP Listener shutdown. {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,509]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Stopped all transport listeners {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,510]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Waiting for request service completion... {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,511]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  All requests have been served. {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,512]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Waiting for deployment completion... {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,512]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  All deployment tasks have been completed. {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,513]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Waiting for server task completion... {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,514]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  All server tasks have been completed. {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,514]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Shutting down WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,514]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Shutting down OSGi framework... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:56,563]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.task.SynapseTaskManager} -  Shutting down the task manager {org.apache.synapse.task.SynapseTaskManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:58,709]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Stopping CarbonServerManager... {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:58,711]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} -  HTTPS Sender shutdown {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:58,712]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} -  HTTP Sender shutdown {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:58,712]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} -  Destroying PassThroughHttpListener {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:58,713]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} -  Destroying PassThroughHttpListener {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:14:58,960]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.CarbonTomcatServiceComponent} -  Stopping the carbon web-app registered under : / {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.CarbonTomcatServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:15:00,251]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Shutdown complete {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-07 22:15:00,252]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Halting JVM {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
```

Comment: Could you please enable wire logs, try your scenario and post here the complete $ESB_HOME/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log. To enable wire logs, uncomment log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG in $ESB_HOME/repository/conf/log4j.properties file and restart ESB. This is to check the content-type of the backend response and the error message you are getting.

Comment: I got it to partly work by deleting the format=soap12 line.  But now I'm getting an HTTP 500 event though it looks like it's working.